# WCF Creating endpoint based on xml data

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, wcf

I have been asked to create a WCF Web Service endpoint which will take data from an xml file as a parameter passed through to it.

I have tried creating a simple WCF Web Service based on a dummy xml file

[image]

The Web Service I created below is in VB.NET and .NET Framework 4.6 and I generated the xml schema in code as OrderedItem at the bottom of the Web Service code, which gets passed in as a parameter to the PushOrderItem OperationContract which is what the customer wants.

```
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface IService

    <OperationContract()>
    Function PushOrderItem(ByVal data As OrderedItem) As String

End Interface

Imports System.Xml.Serialization

Public Class Service
    Implements IService

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Function PushOrderItem(ByVal data As OrderedItem) As String Implements IService.PushOrderItem
        Return "TEST"
    End Function

End Class

<XmlRoot(ElementName:="OrderedItem")>
Public Class OrderedItem
    <XmlElement(ElementName:="ItemName", [Namespace]:="http://www.cpandl.com")>
    Public Property ItemName As String
    <XmlElement(ElementName:="Description", [Namespace]:="http://www.cpandl.com")>
    Public Property Description As String
    <XmlElement(ElementName:="UnitPrice", [Namespace]:="http://www.cohowinery.com")>
    Public Property UnitPrice As String
    <XmlElement(ElementName:="Quantity", [Namespace]:="http://www.cpandl.com")>
    Public Property Quantity As String
    <XmlElement(ElementName:="LineTotal", [Namespace]:="http://www.cohowinery.com")>
    Public Property LineTotal As String
    <XmlAttribute(AttributeName:="inventory", [Namespace]:="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")>
    Public Property Inventory As String
    <XmlAttribute(AttributeName:="money", [Namespace]:="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")>
    Public Property Money As String
End Class
```

The problem I am having though is when I create a WCF Client to try and consume the new end point, it doesn't appear to be working as I expect.

Below is the code for the Console Application I created which reads the xml file (contents added above) and deserialises it as the ServiceReference1.OrderedItem but the request instance of ServiceReference1.OrderedItem just contains all nulls?

```
ServiceReference1.ServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();

var reader = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(ServiceReference1.OrderedItem));
var file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\OrderItem.xml");
ServiceReference1.OrderedItem request = (ServiceReference1.OrderedItem)reader.Deserialize(file);

var response = client.PushOrderItem(request);
```

Can anyone please let me know what I could be doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't see anything obvious.  I usually use instead of StreamReader : System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(@"C:\OrderItem.xml");  I'm confused with your c# and VB.Net mix.  The deserialize is c# while the classes are VB.Net.  I would change the classes to be c#.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for the comment. I know what you mean with VB.NET to C#. I work for  a company that uses VB.NET, hence the API being written that way, but I am more comfortable with C#; hence the client written that way but the client could be written in another language completely different as it's job is simply to consume the SOAP Endpoint.

Comment: If you are getting nulls than the constructor New() is being called, but you are never getting to the method that deserialize the data.

Comment: @jdweng I think the problem is basically although I created the web service based on the Xml Document, the generation of the proxy classes for the service reference i.e. ServiceReference1.OrderedItem on the client doesn't does not take into account the object on the server OrderedItem is based on an Xml Document. Thank you for your responses though. I have been able to send data to my web service via SoapUI instead of creating my own client and it is working as I expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating my own client, I am using SoapUI Open Source https://www.soapui.org/ which is working fine to test my WCF Service.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following example, which successfully deserializes xml:

```
Message m = Message.CreateMessage(XmlReader.Create("C:\OrderItem.xml"), int.MaxValue, MessageVersion.Soap11);
SoapReflectionImporter importer = new SoapReflectionImporter(new SoapAttributeOverrides(), "xxx");
XmlTypeMapping mapp = importer.ImportTypeMapping(typeof(Class name));
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(mapp);
var o = (Class name)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(m.GetReaderAtBodyContents());
```